# Is this a valid use of Skolemization?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, predicate-logic, fake-proofs

Do the steps **1-7** below constitute a valid proof of quantifier exchange? In particular I can seen no justification for line 4. [McCune](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1990/AAAI90-038.pdf) says that the arguments of Skolem functions should serve as place holders for the objects on which the *existing* object depends therefore equality substitution should not be applied to them. However, in **4** I am stating that a Skolem function $skFun(d)$ with one argument is equal to a Skolem constant $c$. I am aware that quantifier exchange is easily proven using other proof techniques such as natural deduction (see an earlier [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119985/proving-a-first-order-logic-theorem-in-equational-logic-with-a-term-rewriting-sy)). My reason for posting this question is that I am using an equational term rewriting system ([CafeOBJ](https://cafeobj.org/)) which can easily process putative proof steps such as those below. How can I justify line **4**?  It seems that I was able to justify the other proof steps with a well known proof technique.

**Theorem:** $\DeclareMathOperator{\Likes}{Likes} (\exists y \forall x :\Likes(x,y)) \Rightarrow (\forall x  \exists y :\Likes(x,y))$
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{1} &&\exists y \forall x:\Likes(x,y) && \text{Assumption}\\
&\textbf{2} &&\forall x:\Likes(x,c) && \text{Existential instantiation  1}\\
&\textbf{3} &&\Likes(d,c) && \text{Universal Elimination 2}\\
&\textbf{4} &&\operatorname{skFun}(d)   =  c && \text{Define Skolem func equal to $c$ ???}\\
&\textbf{5} &&\Likes(d,\operatorname{skFun}(d)) && \text{Apply 4 (right-to-left) to 3}\\
&\textbf{6} &&\forall x:\Likes(x,\operatorname{skFun}(x)) && \text{Universal Instantiation}\\
&\textbf{7} &&\forall x \exists y:\Likes(x,y) && \text{Unskolemize 6}\\
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

My current understanding of lines **1-7** is that the cited justifications are not from natural deduction. To my knowledge, neither Skolemization nor the equation on line **4** can be justified by the rules of natural deduction. Is there a named deduction method used for these proof steps? I suppose I could justify **4** by a semantic model based argument i.e. in any model of the antecedent for any element $d$ there must exist at least one $c$.

Comment: I wouldn't call $(2)$ Skolemization. It's just straightforward existential instantiation. Skolemization is for getting rid of $\exists$s which lie inside $\forall$s, which isn't the case here.

Comment: It makes more sense to re-introduce the quantifiers outside in, i.o.w., swap lines 6 and 7. The rest looks fine to me.

Comment: @Noah In the case of an outer existential quantifier does Skolemization and existential instantiation give the same results?

Comment: @lemontree The steps seem OK, but I am not sure why.